# how do i prevent scrolling on my page?

Tags: javascript, php, css

> Hi guys i want my webpage to display everything on it without
>   scrolling down or up to view anything. Please how can i do it?
>   it has been giving me some difficulties.
>
> Here is my layout.css

```
body {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#Holder {
    width:980px;
    height: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 21px;
    margin-bottom: 21px;
}
#Header {
    height: 150px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}
#NavBar {
    height: 60px;
    background-color:rgb(13, 13, 13);
}
#Content {
    height:auto;
    clear:both;
    overflow:auto;
}
#PageHeading {
    height:auto;
    padding:11px;
}
#ContentLeft {
    width:280px;
    float:left;
    padding-top:11px;
    padding-left:11px;
}
#ContentRight {
    width:680px;
    float:right;
}
#Footer {
    height:100px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    width:50%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Please the question is different from what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0):

Add one of this to your code:

overflow-x: hidden;
would hide any thing on the x-axis that goes outside of the element, so there would be no need for the horizontal scrollbar and it get removed.

overflow-y: hidden;
would hide any thing on the y-axis that goes outside of the element, so there would be no need for the vertical scrollbar and it get removed.

overflow: hidden;
would remove both scrollbars

Comment: I want the page to display the whole content on the webpage after the scroll button is hidden. How can I do that, please?